# Ubuntu 16.04 - Sublime Text don't show the menu in the menubar

Tags: ubuntu, menu, sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04

I already try to edit the file  `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session`. But all the variables "menu_visible" are already defined as "true".

[image]

I think this problem is in Ubuntu 16.04, because another softwares like GIMP and the Terminal also not show the menu.

Comment: It is a confirmed bug of Ubuntu 16.04. [This link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar) solved my problem,

Answer (score -2):

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session[0].start.pid="(YOURPID)"
```

Comment: What does this even mean? It's not an answer, and there's zero explanation.